# Como obter os dados de uma BulletedList no CodeBehind ASP.NET?

Tags: jquery, c#, html, asp.net, webforms

Tenho uma lista de itens definida através de uma [BulletedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.bulletedlist(v=vs.110).aspx) em uma página Asp.net. Essa lista é populada com vários itens através dos atributos `DataSource`, `DataTextField`, `DataValueField` e do método `DataBind()` no CodeBehind em C#.

Eu preciso que o usuário possa reordenar os itens dessa lista e depois a página possa salvar essa nova lista ordenada no lugar da lista antiga. Para isso, eu implementei o Sortable de jQuery, seguindo esses dois links: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860481/how-to-get-drag-and-drop-functionality-in-asp-net-4-0-using-ajax) e [[2]](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/).

Até aí tudo bem, está funcionando tudo normalmente. Porém, na hora de salvar, eu preciso pegar essa lista de volta (mais precisamente, os valores de `DataValueField`), para salvar as alterações, e é esta minha dúvida: **como poderia pegar esses valores de volta no CodeBehind?**

Obs.: por algum motivo não tenho acesso aos métodos `GetData()` e `GetDataSource()`, o que poderia ajudar nessa questão.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a propriedade `Items`, irá ficar algo do tipo

```
for (int i=0; i<BULLETEDLIST.Items.Count; i++) {
         if (BULLETEDLIST.Items[i].Selected)
            RETURN;
      }
```

No lugar de `return` você coloca a lógica do seu código, pode criar um array e salvar nesse array os itens de acordo com as posições atuais.

Comment: Essa é uma boa abordagem para se obter os itens da lista ordenada, porém não funciona quando os itens são reordenados. Neste caso, ele retorna a mesma lista, mesmo que a ordem da lista seja alterada.

Comment: Mas ele não está pegando de volta a lista inicial por causa do `PostBack` ?